# Using a cache vs a really fast database

Tags: caching, redis

I have an application that needs to store some data(key avalues)during the payment of customers. The data is not sensitive and doesn’t really need to be stored for long. Maybe a maximum of a couple of days. Should I use a cache and ignore the database or should I use a really fast db like redis.

Comment: What if your database is fast enough and it doesn't matter? Redis is really only useful if you have heavy write and/or read activity. It's not helpful with low levels of read/write.

Comment: Yes, it is goin to be read write heavy. But, if not redis, then what better options do I have. Like I mentioned above, I’m going to have to store some data for like a couple of days and delete them. But the data volume per day will be high.

Comment: Postgres 11 performs extremely well even under heavy read/write loads. You can set up a procedure to clear out old data, or just run a query to purge it if necessary.